# Is there any way to set default value in CharField of django model?

Tags: django

How to set default value in:

I want to send default value Individual everytime in Individua_type

```
class Dispatcher(models.Model):
    individual_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=Individual)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign default callback method to char field, you can write the logic in this method.

```
models.CharField(max_length=7, default=individual)

def individual():
    # you can define incremental logic or static value.
    return 'some string'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes. Use **`default="Individual"`** (with quotes)

```
class Dispatcher(models.Model):
    individual_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Individual")
```

In Python, strings are defined within ***double quotes ("foo" )*** or ***single quotes ('foo')***

---

You'll get more detailed information from the [**`default` - Django Official Doc**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#default).

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the quotes because is a string. When you are going to save the object, do not instantiate the attribute `individual_type`, the default will instantiate it.

```
class Dispatcher(models.Model):
    individual_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Individual')
```